# Latest time of a date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a column (REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP) in a table which shows date in format YY-MM-DD. I would like select the latest (by time) of a certain date (let's say Aug 31, 2011). The first column should be the timestamp in hh24:mm:ss and the rest should be all columns (*) of this table. How do I do it?

Using Oracle 2.1.1.64

REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP - NOT NULL - DATE

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  What version?  And what have you tried?

Comment: What RDBMS? (SQL Server, MySQL, ORACLE, etc)  And what is the datatype of the `REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP` field?

Comment: Oracle 2.1.1.64. I don't know how to find out the datatype. Pls advise how.

Comment: Sounds like you are using SQL Developer 2.1.1.64... that is your client program version not the database server version.

Comment: You want the latest record on the specified date only or any record before that date?

Comment: @Magnus - the latest record on the specified date only. Thx.

Comment: @Prostak ok, updated my answer, hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP IN
(  
    SELECT
       MAX(REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP) as REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP
    FROM
       Table
    WHERE
       TO_CHAR(REC_CREATE_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD') = '20110831'
)
```

**EDITED for Oracle**

Comment: It gives me a few rows. How do I select the latest one?

Comment: Lets say another column is Username and PhoneNr, if you group by that you'll get the latest record for each user with the same PhoneNr.

Comment: @Prostak -- it's fixed.  I added the 'other fields' to the answer later -- wasn't paying attention.

Comment: @Magnus, thank you very much. But this answer worked the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName As tbl1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM tableName as tbl2
  WHERE
    tbl2.rec_create_timestamp > '2001-08-30'
    tbl2.rec_create_timestamp < '2001-09-01'
  HAVING MAX(tbl2.rec_create_timestamp) = tbl1.rec_create_timestamp
)
```

Comment: Ok, removed the TOP. If two or more records have the same latest date, you'll now get all.

Answer (score -1):

For a generalised answer that can work with Sets of data rather than individual dates...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(rec_create_timestamp) ORDER BY rec_create_timestamp DESC) AS daily_sequence_id,
    TRUNC(rec_create_timestamp) as rec_create_date,
    *
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  daily_sequence_id = 1
  AND rec_create_date = '20110831'
```

Comment: Holy smokes...Just because you ***can*** order anchovies on your pizza doesn't mean you ***should***!

Comment: Benefit of anchovies : it works for a set of dates, not just one.

Comment: Make it `(PARTITION BY TRUNC(rec_create_timestamp))` and `TRUNC(rec_create_timestamp) as rec_create_date` and then you have the oracle version

Comment: Just kidding about the anchovies.  But isn't simpler better in this case?  A simple SELECT with a MAX() aggregate, versus a select + CTE + ranking function?

Comment: If the OP only wants to do it for a single date, sure.  This is just a different option that is designed to work with SETs rather than single values.

Comment: To whomever down-voted, care to elaborate as to why this is so wrong that it's better to vote down rather than simply vote up an alternative answer?